# How can I record a verbal or sound to use as a ringtone for specific numbers

Tags: ios, iphone, recording, ringtones

I have an iPhone 4S with iOS 5.

How do I record speech or sound to use as a ringtone dedicated to certain phone numbers, especially numbers that aren't in my address book?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is two questions. How do I record ringtones? and How do I get a ringtone for non-contacts? I will address the second.

You cannot explicitly set a ringtone for numbers not in you address book. But, you can get this effect. Simply make sure all your contacts have a "custom" ringtone set. Then, set your default ringtone to something else. You can do this with only two ringtones, one for contacts and one for the non-contacts. Or, you could customize your contacts as much as you want. Just make sure that every time you add a contact you give them a rintone other than the default.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the first of these two questions. Once you've recorded audio (e.g. with [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net)):

- Add each sound file to iTunes
- Right click each and convert to AAC

  - If you see "Convert to MP3" or otherwise in the context menu, visit *Preferences > General > CD Import Settings > Import Using AAC Encoder*
- Reveal those files in Finder and rename their extensions from .m4a to .m4r
- Add the .m4r files to your iTunes Library (they'll automatically be added to the Tones section)

  - If you don't see Tones in your library, visit *Preferences > General > Show > Tones*
- Remove the entries for the original clips from iTunes (sort by Date Added to quickly round them up). (iTunes probably won't ask whether to keep/trash originals in this case, since these files are missing, as far as it knows.)
- Connect your iPhone, visit the Tones tab, and choose to sync all tones

You should now see your tones on your iPhone under *Settings > Sounds > Ringtone*. Refer to [Morgan Wise's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/37031/12625) for a trick to have separate ringtones for known & unknown numbers. (That's not something that's supported by default on iPhone.)

Source: [Simonblog](http://www.simonblog.com/2010/09/06/how-to-create-ringtone-for-iphone-on-itunes-10/).